# How to parse html and return the elements value in an array in order of apperance in the html?

Tags: php, domdocument, querypath

This code uses http://querypath.org and http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

What I would like to do is get all tags in $types and go through $html and save the output to an array in order of that tags appearance in html
e.g

```
.imageBlock,h1,h2,p,h5,h1,h2,p,.imageblock,h4
```

this is the order the final array must have how would I do this?

```
$html = <<<html
<section>
    <div class=" imageBlock" style="background: url('1.jpg');"></div>   
<div>
    <h1>H1 .1</h1>
    <h2>H2. 1</h2>
    <p>p .1</p>
</div>      
 <h5>Here is an H5</h5>
<div>
    <h1>H1 .2</h1>
    <h2>H2. 2</h2>
    <p>p .2</p>
</div>
<div class="imageBlock" style="background: url('2.jpg');"></div>    

<h4>Test</h4>
<section>
html;

$types = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p', '.imageBlock'];

foreach($types as $type) {
    //Create a varible for each tag
    ${"$type"} = htmlqp($html, $type);
}

foreach($types as $type) {
    $types = (${"$type"}); //Easier to use varible
    $nodes = []; //Array to hold elements in order of appperance not sure if in correct place?
    foreach($types as $tag) {
        if($types->length !== 0) {
            //Show all elements
            for($i = 0 ; $i< $types->length; $i++) {
                echo $type;
                var_dump($types->get()[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: You can store each element's start position. Then, you can order the result by elements' start positions to get the elements in order of their appearance in the HTML code.

Comment: @TurgutSarıçam Could you give me an example of how to store the elements' start position?

Comment: You can use `strpos` function. E.g. `$pos = strpos($html, "<h1")` gives you the start position of h1 element. If you expect another h1 later, you can use old position to define an offset. E.g. `$pos2 = strpos($html, "<h1", $pos + 1)`

Comment: You might be able to use like simplehtmldom and just traverse through the list and get the tags in order.

Comment: You could try using [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/212940), if you dare .